# Let $Tf(x)=\int_{[0,x]}fdm$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Use the Open Mapping Theorem to prove that $T: L^1[0,1] \rightarrow C_0((0,1])$ is not onto.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $Tf(x)=\int_{[0,x]}fdm$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Use the Open Mapping Theorem to prove that $T: L^1[0,1] \rightarrow C_0((0,1])$ is not onto.

Where $C_0((0,1])=\{f \in C[0,1] : f(0)=0\}$

---

My attempt:

I am examining the action of $T$ on the functions $t \rightarrow e^{int}$. I am sort of running into a wall. If somebody could help me I'd greatly appreciate it.. I've been trying to figure this out for days now!

Comment: What is $C_0((0,1])$? Functions of compact support on $(0,1]$?

Comment: Wow, can't believe I forgot that, haha. edited.

Comment: Clearly $\|T\|\leq 1$ and $T$ is one-to-one. If $T$ is onto, the open mapping theorem implies that $T^{-1}$ is bounded. Now, perhaps find an $f$ with large $L^1$ norm but $\|Tf\|_\infty$ is small (which means that $f$ needs to oscillate heavily)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT.- (1) Choose an open ball $B(0;r)$ in $L_1$ and take $S=B(0;r)\setminus\{0\}$. This $S$ is still open in $L_1$.

(2) Choose a sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $S$ converging to $0$ (you do have a lot of possibilities!).

(3) In general your  choice $\{f_n\}$ will be such that $\{T(f_n)\}$ converges to $0$ in your $C_0$(to you to avoid exceptions).

Since in this case the sequence $\{T(f_n)\}$ converges to an element in its border, the set $T(S)$ can not be open. Consequently $T$ is not onto by the Open Mapping Theorem.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your argument. How does showing that $\{T(f_n)\}$ converges to $0$ show that $T(S)$ is not open?

Comment: THanks a ton Piquito!! Can you please expand on this though? I am also lookin at what Joey said and a bit confused.